# Trying to access excel COM object as admin user

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, comobject

**The objective** is to access the running Excel workbook  in the machine.  Intention is to close the respective workbook though this application which was opened by the user.

**Achieved:** I used the following code snippet to access the Excel COM object

```
        Excel.Application instance = null;            
        try
        {
            instance = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)//Excel not open
        {
            wasFoundRunning = false;
        }

        if (wasFoundRunning)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Workbook ss in instance.Workbooks)
            {
                string s = ss.Name;                    
            }
        }
```

**Issue:** Above code works only if the excel sheet and the application opened by the same user in the machine.  I have to run the application as administrator and it fails.  Exception as follows and it means that it cannot find any excel sheet running.

```
Exception:  Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
```

***It fails if I run my application elevated and user opens the sheet.***

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Why are you trying to *start Excel* like this instead of using the Excel Interop library? And what does "fails if I run elevated" mean? Is an exception thrown? What is the full message? How do you even know since you *hide* the exception with that `catch {}`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos updated my question